# Using GroupBy in Linq complex

Tags: linq

Here is my table structure

**table1 - PLAYER**

- PlayerID
- FirstName
- LastName
- EmailAddress
- CellNo

**Table2 - Team**

- TeamID
- TeamName

**Table3 - TEAMPLAYERS**

- ID
- PlayerID
- TeamID

A player can be part of more than one team. 
Question:
Now I want to get the player basic details along with the count of no. of teams he plays for. I use the following query to get the result in SQL:

```
SELECT P.FirstName, P.LastName, P.EmailAddress, P.CellNo, COUNT(TP.TeamID) 
FROM Player P 
JOIN TeamPlayer TP ON P.PlayerID = TP.PlayerID 
GROUP BY P.PlayerID, P.FirstName, P.Lastname, P.EmailAddress, P.CellNo;
```

This works perfectly.

However, im stuck when converting this to linq. Not much of help from online resources. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Database Contexts `dbContext.Players` and `dbContext.TeamPlayers` are just representational, check your project for right context

```
var result=  (from player in dbContext.Players
             join teamPlayer in dbContext.TeamPlayers
             on  player.PlayerID equals teamPlayer.PlayerID
             select new{player,teamPlayer})
            .GroupBy(P=>new
                        {
                         P.PlayerID,
                         P.FirstName,
                         P.Lastname,
                         P.EmailAddress,
                         P.CellNo
                        })
            .Select(x=>new
                       {
                        x.Key.FirstName, 
                        x.Key.LastName, 
                        x.Key.EmailAddress, 
                        x.Key.CellNo,
                        TeamIDCount=x.Count(z=>z.teamPlayer.TeamID)
                       }).ToList();
```